# WPF xamgrid row by row commit behaviour for new row not working

Tags: c#, infragistics, xamgrid

I am using XamGrid control for datainput from end user.  Databinding is working

For the xamgrid, I have added a new line at the bottom of the table and have kept the following settings:

IsMouseActionEditingEnabled="SingleClick" IsOnCellActiveEditingEnabled="False" AllowAddNewRow="Bottom" Style="{StaticResource addNewRowCellStyle}"/>

Now the requirement is that if user enters on the new row cell, then the active cell should be the first cell of the first row in the xamgrid so I wrote the following code in the ActiveCellChanged event to work it out

private void dataCurveGrid_ActiveCellChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      Infragistics.Controls.Grids.CellBase type = dataCurveGrid.ActiveCell;

```
  if (type is Infragistics.Controls.Grids.Primitives.AddNewRowCell) 
  {
             if (dataCurveGrid.Rows.Count != 0)         
             {
                 dataCurveGrid.Rows[0].Cells[0].IsActive = true;                      }             }                    }
```

The above requirement is working but

Now my hurdle is because of above ActiveCellChanged method the behaviour of data entered on new row control is getting committed cell by cell instead of row by row which is required by me and was happening before this method.

Please advice what should I do to make the user data get committed row by row.

Also please inform if any alternate method is there to solve the above user requirement and not disturb the above row by row commitment.

Thanks in advance

Rakesh

Comment: Does changing the UpdateMode of the grid to be OnRecordChange or OnRecordChangeOrLostFocus give you the behavior you are looking for? http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WPF/Current/CLR4.0/?page=InfragisticsWPF4.DataPresenter.v13.1~Infragistics.Windows.DataPresenter.UpdateMode.html

Answer (score 1):

I am not completely sure that I understand your requirement, but as I much as I did, I can say that the behavior you have is expected since when you change the Active Cell from the AddNewRow to an existing Row, the AddNewRow commit its Changes.